# jQuery UI Tabs not working in Wordpress 4.4 and later

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

In my Wordpress theme, I have a Theme Options page which is using jQuery UI tabs.
These tabs perfectly works in Wordpress versions below 4.4. But they don't seem to work in the versions later than 4.4

It just don't give any error or anything. The other jQuery functions (such as jQuery color-picker, slider..etc.) in the options page are working fine. It's just the tabs which are broken.

In the console I get this message

```
Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.
```

It's from the `jQuery.js` file which is included in `wp-include/js/jQuery` folder

This is my code...

```
<div class="ui-tabs">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">

       foreach ( $this->sections as $section_slug => $section )
         echo '<li><a href="#' . $section_slug . '">' . $section . '</a></li>';

      </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
            var sections = [];';

            foreach ( $this->sections as $section_slug => $section )
                    echo "sections['$section'] = '$section_slug';";

            echo 'var wrapped = jQuery(".wrap h3").wrap("<div class=\"ui-tabs-panel\">");
            wrapped.each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).parent().append(jQuery(this).parent().nextUntil("div.ui-tabs-panel"));
            });
            jQuery(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(index) {
                    jQuery(this).attr("id", sections[jQuery(this).children("h3").text()]);
                    if (index > 0)
                            jQuery(this).addClass("ui-tabs-hide");
            });
            jQuery(".ui-tabs").tabs({
                    fx: { opacity: "toggle", duration: "fast" }
            });

            jQuery("input[type=text], textarea").each(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr("placeholder") || jQuery(this).val() == "")
                            jQuery(this).css("color", "#999");
            });

            jQuery("input[type=text], textarea").focus(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr("placeholder") || jQuery(this).val() == "") {
                            jQuery(this).val("");
                            jQuery(this).css("color", "#000");
                    }
            }).blur(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() == "" || jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                            jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr("placeholder"));
                            jQuery(this).css("color", "#999");
                    }
            });

            jQuery(".wrap h3, .wrap table").show();

            // This will make the "warning" checkbox class really stand out when checked.
            // I use it here for the Reset checkbox.
            jQuery(".warning").change(function() {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked"))
                            jQuery(this).parent().css("background", "#c00").css("color", "#fff").css("fontWeight", "bold");
                    else
                            jQuery(this).parent().css("background", "none").css("color", "inherit").css("fontWeight", "normal");
            });

            // Browser compatibility
            if (jQuery.browser.mozilla) 
                     jQuery("form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

What's the reason for this odd behavior ? Is it something in my code ? But it works fine in older versions of WP. Any clue ?

Comment: FYI: `jQuery.browser` was deprecated in version 1.3, seven years ago ?

Comment: Also, the mixing of PHP and javascript seems to not be very valid.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tested the code by removing jQuery.browser. But still  it's same. But why this works in older versions and not in latest ?

Comment: Who knows, there's many strange things here, like PHP inside JS without PHP tags, probably not using `wp_enqueue_script` like you should, with `localize_script` to pass data etc. There's also an entire section of JS that just sets color based on value, and doesn't seem to be related to the issue at all. Try to remove parts of the JS until the error stops appearing, at least then you'll know what's causing it.

Comment: Have you figured out what's going on behind the screen? because I have the same issue.

Comment: @shaz3e Yes I figured a solution and just posted it as an answer. Check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured the answer for my own question...

Actually, this error was because of WP's some core changes in the backend interface. They've changed the Backend headings structure So, your `<h3>` tag in WordPress 4.3, is no longer `<h3>` anymore in 4.4 and higher.

So, in the custom options page, in WP 4.3, the titles were rendered as `<h2>` tags. And, that titles were binded to my javascript code as `.h2`. So, that's where the error occurred.

That small error caused the entire JavaScript block to malfunction. So, jQuery tabs didn't work.

You can explore this with inspector. See the image below.

[image]

As you can see the Titles in Wordpress 4.3 were rendered as `<h3>` but in Wordpress 4.4, they're `<h2>`

So, what I did was just adjusting my JavaScript code to bind the Title as both `.h2` and `.h3`

From this...

```
jQuery(this).children("h2").text();
```

To like this...

```
jQuery(this).children("h2, h3").text();
```

This did work for me. Your code may be different than mine. But, the cause for the problem can be it...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that fixed mine too I had to change a little bit more

var wrapped = $(".wrap h2, .wrap h3").wrap("<div class=\"ui-tabs-panel\">");

$(".wrap h2, .wrap h3, .wrap table").show();

Comment: also if you have some static content h2 or h3 headings it will also apply on this so beaware don't use static content with h2/h3 tags

Comment: Yeah, glad this answer helped you. :)

Comment: have your created a theme using same method? would you like to share it with me? my repo on github github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress

Comment: Yup. It's still under development. I'll share it with ur repo soon.