# How to use IRIS Color Picker instead of farbtastic

Tags: wordpress, farbtastic

Since [Farbtastic is deprecated](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) I want to use [Iris (Colour picker)](https://github.com/automattic/Iris) instead in my theme options page after spending hours on internet search I found so manything I tried some of them too but didn't worked for me might someone here more genius could help me to figure it out where I am committing a mistake. below are codes examples what I currently have with farbtastic which is working fine.

here is my [repo on github](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress)

in [s3-options.php](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress/blob/master/s3framework/s3-options.php) on line 374

```
public function scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_print_scripts( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
}
```

and my custom script in [assets/script.js](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress/blob/master/s3framework/assets/script.js) on line 74

```
$('#header_text_color_id').hide();
$('#header_text_color_id').farbtastic('#header_text_color');

$('#header_text_color').click(function() {
    $('#header_text_color_id').fadeIn();
});

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('#header_text_color_id').each(function() {
        var display = $(this).css('display');
        if ( display == 'block' )
            $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});

$('#header_background_color_id').hide();
$('#header_background_color_id').farbtastic('#header_background_color');

$('#header_background_color').click(function() {
    $('#header_background_color_id').fadeIn();
});

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('#header_background_color_id').each(function() {
        var display = $(this).css('display');
        if ( display == 'block' )
            $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

and my css are

```
.color-picker{
    position:relative;
}
.color-picker .color-picker-box{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border:solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    padding:1em;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

which is working like charm 
[image] 
now I want to use IRIS please help to get done with it. if you can do it on github would be great for me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if I understand you correctly you need the following. I had something on hand so I altered it a bit to suit your needs.

First I created a submenu page (I was testing this to see if it works, but you can just implement this in your own options, it should be working just fine)

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_color_in_options' );

if (!function_exists('mytheme_add_color_in_options')) {
    function mytheme_add_color_in_options(){
        add_menu_page( esc_html__('Options', 'mytheme'), esc_html__('Options', 'mytheme'), 'manage_options', 'theme_options', 'mytheme_add_options', 'dashicons-admin-tools
    ', '25' );
    }
}
```

Then I enqueued necessary scripts

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_enqueue_color_picker' );

function mw_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    if ($hook_suffix == 'toplevel_page_theme_options') {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/options.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );

        // If you're using WPML, a nice 'trick' to have

        $ajaxurl = '';
        if( in_array('sitepress-multilingual-cms/sitepress.php', get_option('active_plugins')) ){
            $ajaxurl .= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?lang=' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE );
        } else{
            $ajaxurl .= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');
        }

        wp_localize_script( 'my-script-handle', 'options_ajax', array(
            'ajaxurl'                => $ajaxurl,
            'settings_saved'         => esc_html__('Settings Saved', 'mytheme')
        ));

    }
}
```

I'm saving the options with AJAX so I localized the `admin-ajax.php` as well. But the important part is the `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );`. This is what actually includes the color picker. I placed all this in the `functions.php` but you can add it in a separate options page if you wish.

As recommended [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) I am checking if I'm on my options page with `if ($hook_suffix == 'toplevel_page_theme_options')`, and then I get my scripts enqueued.

Next is the page render and ajax save:

```
if (!function_exists('mytheme_add_options')) {
    function mytheme_add_options(){
        echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>'.esc_html__('Theme Options', 'mytheme').'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.esc_html__('Add your theme options.', 'mytheme').'</p>';

        $text_color = get_option('text_color', '');

        echo '<style>
            #options_form .spinner {
                background: url(images/spinner.gif) no-repeat;
                -webkit-background-size: 20px 20px;
                background-size: 20px 20px;
                display: inline-block;
                visibility: hidden;
                float:none;
                vertical-align: middle;
                opacity: .7;
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                margin: -2px 10px 0;
            }
            .saved_options{
                color: #093;
            }
            </style>
            <form id="options_form" class="options_form" method="post" action="#">
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="text_color">'.esc_html__('Text Color', 'mytheme').'</label></th>
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="text_color" id="text_color" value="'.esc_attr($text_color).'"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" class="submit button button-primary" value="'.esc_html__('Save', 'mytheme').'"><span class="spinner"></span><span class="saved_options"></span><input type="hidden" name="ajaxnonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'options_form' ) . '">
                <input type="hidden" name="ajaxnonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'options_form' ) . '">
            </form></div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_mytheme_options_page_save', 'mytheme_options_page_save' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mytheme_options_page_save', 'mytheme_options_page_save' );

if (!function_exists('mytheme_options_page_save')) {
    function mytheme_options_page_save() {

        $nonce = $_POST['ajaxnonce'];

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'options_form' ) ){
            die ('BUSTED');
        }

        if (isset($_POST['text_color'])) {
            update_option('text_color', stripslashes( $_POST['text_color']) );
            $text_color = stripslashes( $_POST['text_color'] );
        }

        if( isset($_POST['text_color']) ) {
            die();
        }

    }
}
```

This just renders the form with hidden input field where you'll initialize your color picker. And the last part is the javascript of course. In your `options.js` add

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    'use strict';

    $('#text_color').wpColorPicker();

    /* AJAX Options Save */

    $('#options_form').submit(function(){
        var $form = $(this);
        var str= $form.serialize() + '&action=mytheme_options_page_save';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: options_ajax.ajaxurl,
            data: str,
            success: function(){
                $('.saved_options').text(options_ajax.settings_saved).delay(2000).fadeOut();
            },
            beforeSend : function () {
                $('.saved_options').text('').show();
                $('#options_form .spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
            },
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html(jqXHR + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
            },
            complete : function () {
                $('#options_form .spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The `$('#text_color').wpColorPicker();` will initialize the color picker, and the rest is for the AJAX save.

Once all this is in, you'll have this:

[image]

And you pull your option with

```
get_option('text_color', '');
```

If you want to you can set the default color, both in the color picker and in the `get_option()`. On the link above you have all the info you need.

Hope this helped :)

**EDIT**

In your `s3-options.php` on line 374 add

```
public function scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_print_scripts( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
}
```

And in `script.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#header_text_color_id').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Now, your `script.js` is poorly written. You have four

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){});
```

blocks. What for? You only need one, and put everything inside.

Now if the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#header_text_color_id').wpColorPicker();
});
```

won't work for some reason you can try with:

```
$('.color_picker input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    $(this).wpColorPicker();
});
```

This should trigger color picker on your color input fields.

### BIG EDIT

So I had to dig a bit into your framework, but I got it to work. You'll need to modify it (remove the unnecessary text fields, and javascript that governs the old `farbtastic` trigger).

First comment out (then remove once you've done editing) the `farbtastic` styles and scripts in `s3-options.php` file

```
public function scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    // wp_enqueue_style( 'farbtastic' );
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'farbtastic' );
    wp_print_scripts( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
}
```

In your `script.js` you'll need to comment out (remove)

```
// $('#header_background_color_id').farbtastic('#header_background_color');
```

And the fade in methods that will interfere with the color picker.

Next, back in `s3-options.php` inside the `__construct()` after

```
add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'register_settings' ) );
```

add

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'my_enqueue_color_picker' ) );
```

After that add:

```
/**
 * Add color picker enqueue
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
public function my_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {

    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    if ($hook_suffix == 'toplevel_page_s3-theme-options') {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/s3framework/assets/options.js', array('wp-color-picker'), false, true );
    }

}
```

I've set it so that you have `options.js` file, but you can change this to your `scripts.js` file as well. Inside the `options.js` is just:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#header_text_color_id').wpColorPicker();
});
```

which adds:

[image]

For the rest, just style the input field to hidden, and remove the old field, and unnecessary scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I have class and then I defined all sections and settings now I really don't know where should i use that code.

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it's ok. One thing I'm not sure of. If you wrote the entire framework, you should know how to put a simple color picker in the options :\

Comment: I'll try it when I get home on my comp to see what could be the issue. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you pls download my repository from github and check it out yourself I am figuring it out here too but all going wroing.

Comment: thank you so much for your time but it is not just working for me can you please send updates on github it is just not working for me when I try your updates tabs doesn't work.

Comment: I've created the updates on github, please see them. If they don't work, change the `scripts.js` to `options.js`, and add the `options.js` file in the assets folder.

Comment: Ops I forgot that Sorry.

Comment: Hey dingo_d since I have updated my wordpress 4.2.2 my tabs are not working any idea???

Comment: I have also updated a questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246680/jquery-ui-tabs-not-working-in-theme-options-on-latest-version-of-wordpress

Comment: When enqueuing your script that will toggle the colorpicker, be sure to enqueue `jquery-ui-tabs` as a [dependency](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: I am trying to enqueue the script but still not working here is the code I am using 

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs', bloginfo('url') . '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/tabs.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.4', false );

Comment: No need to do it like that. You can use the hook for the iris color picker and add jquery ui dependency: `wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/s3framework/assets/scripts.js', array('wp-color-picker', 'jquery-ui-tabs'), false, true );`. In the link I provided you have a list of included scripts that come with wordpress...

Comment: Thanks @dingo_d I will check it at home and let you know

Comment: I tried but its still not working. here is code I am using

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/s3framework/assets/js/options.js', array('wp-color-picker', 'jquery-ui-tabs'), false, true );

on console I am getting this error: Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

Comment: You need to enqueue it to the script that is loaded on the options page. You need to find which script is always loaded on that page, and put it there...

Comment: jquery-ui-tabs is being open I check and source page its being called from wp directory.

Comment: There's no error on console can you please download repo from github master not a release and suggest update there?

Comment: for now the problem got solved here is the solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658758/jquery-ui-tabs-not-working-in-wordpress-4-4-and-later?answertab=active#tab-top