# jquery-ui-tabs not working in theme options on latest version of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, tabs

Since I have updated my wordpress installation to 4.2.2 jquery-ui-tabs is not working at theme options page I am loading it at line # 458 in [s3-options.php](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress/blob/master/s3framework/s3-options.php#L456) I also have another file which contains jQuery which was perfectly working on previous version of wordpress I am pasting the code below also the file is host on [github](https://github.com/Shaz3e/S3-Wordpress/blob/master/s3framework/assets/js.php).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var sections = [];
    <?php foreach ( $this->sections as $section_slug => $section ){
        echo "sections['$section'] = '$section_slug';";
    }?>
    var wrapped = $(".wrap h3").wrap("<div class=\"ui-tabs-panel\">");
    wrapped.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().append($(this).parent().nextUntil("div.ui-tabs-panel"));
    });

    $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("id", sections[$(this).children("h3").text()]);
            if (index > 0)
                $(this).addClass("ui-tabs-hide");
    });

    $(".ui-tabs").tabs({
        fx: { opacity: "toggle", duration: "fast" }
    });

    $("input[type=text], textarea").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder") || $(this).val() == "")
                $(this).css("color", "#999");
        });

        $("input[type=text], textarea").focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder") || $(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).val("");
                $(this).css("color", "#000");
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                $(this).css("color", "#999");
            }
        });

        $(".wrap h3, .wrap table").show();

        // This will make the "warning" checkbox class really stand out when checked.
        // I use it here for the Reset checkbox.
        $(".warning").change(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                $(this).parent().css("background", "#c00").css("color", "#fff").css("fontWeight", "bold");
            else
                $(this).parent().css("background", "none").css("color", "inherit").css("fontWeight", "normal");

});

// Browser compatibility
if ($.browser.mozilla)
    $("form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
});
```

Please help me to figured out

Comment: Which theme and which version of that theme? Any errors in the browser's developer console?

Comment: @Technoh This is my own developed theme and there is no error message related to ui-tabs in console.